# handle tasks with mongodb and rabbitmq

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rabbitmq

I subscribed to the job, and listened for new messages, I got an ID which is just like MongoDB's ObjectId.
When I use native MongoDB driver, all works well, but when I tried to use Mongoose I got this error : `findOne` method returned previous values from queue.

What I tried:

```
q.subscribe((message, headers, deliveryInfo, ack) => {
    const workerId = message.workerId; // everytime changed, it`s ok!
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
      const collection = db.collection('workers');
      collection.findOne({_id: workerId}, (err, item) => {
        logger.info('native ', item); // return actual data by id
      });
    });

    Workers.findOne(workerId, (err, item) => {
      logger.info('mongoose ', item); // return previos value! why??? workerId changed it other values, because it another job
    });
});
```

So, mongoose returned old object while I did not run

```
ack.acknowledge(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

call `Workers.findById(workerId, ...` and it will return what you want